# Errbit is very noisy, can I limit what it outputs

Tags: logging, output, errbit

When I start errbit, I route its output to a log file. This file get's huge every day.

I know I can rotate it, or route it's output to the bit bucket, but I thought it might be better to just turn down the errorlevel...

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the environment variable `ERRBIT_LOG_LEVEL` to change the log level to something more useful for you. Try:

```
ERRBIT_LOG_LEVEL=error
```